# Cannot convert string to array using visual studio code

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, split

I am trying to convert a string into an array using string.split('') method or [...string] or Array.from(string).

For example one of the methods I am using is:

[image]

```
const string='word';
string.split('');
console.log(string)
```

The result of this code in the console is ->    word  and I was expecting ['w', 'o', 'r', 'd']

Can someone let me know if I am doing something wrong or is there a bug in Visual Studio Code or am I loosing my mind?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi, You are printing the string on console, you need to assign the `split` to a new variable and then print that variable.

Comment: Inside console log write string.split('') like so 
console.log(string.split(''));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is not Visual Studio Code. Is Javascript. VS Code is just an IDE and you will get the very same result whatever place you write that code. The problem is that `split()` do not modify the variable, but just returns a new value. Try this:

```js
const string = 'word';
const word = string.split('');
console.log(word);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Sorry if the question sounded childish.

Comment: @RobertPascui no problem. We are here to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it right to split, but you need to assign it to a new variable.

```js
const string = 'word';

const ans = string.split('');

console.log(ans)
```

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

from the above link you can clearly understand how string.split() work it does not modify the original content but create an array so you have to store it somewhere

here's my code

```
const string = 'word';
const result = string.split('')
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const string='programming';
const newString=string.split('');
console.log(newString)//["p", "r", "o", "g", "r", "a", "m", "m", "i", "n", "g"]
```

You need to assign the **split** output in a new variable and print the variable